# Where is PriviledgedHandler definition?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-3

In class [`com.sun.xml.wss.impl.misc.WSITProviderSecurityEnvironment`](http://grepcode.com/file/maven.java.net/content/groups/promoted/org.glassfish.metro/webservices-osgi/2.3.1-b018/com/sun/xml/wss/impl/misc/WSITProviderSecurityEnvironment.java#WSITProviderSecurityEnvironment) is defined fileld `_handler = new PriviledgedHandler(handler);`

Where is `PriviledgedHandler` class definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source on linked page is not whole (showed 2515 of 3191 rows). When I want see whole class I must download source code.

Comment: Seems like you're using old browsers like IE8. I can see the whole with IE9, Firefox 21 and Chrome 27. And please see the change of my answer.

Comment: I have firefox 21.0 on lubuntu 12.04. Maybe is problem in proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see the link in the source you provided (`WSITProviderSecurityEnvironment.java`)?

`_handler = new PriviledgedHandler(handler);`

And it will lead you to the bottom of the source:

```
    class PriviledgedHandler implements CallbackHandler {

        CallbackHandler delegate = null;

        public PriviledgedHandler(CallbackHandler handler) {
            delegate = handler;
        }

        public void handle(final Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {
            AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {

                public Object run() {
                    try {
                        delegate.handle(callbacks);
                        return null;
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        throw new XWSSecurityRuntimeException(ex);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `PriviledgedHandler` is an inner class of `WSITProviderSecurityEnvironment`

Comment: It is only constructor call. Not class definition.